# How can I get a count for each row in separate table?

Tags: sql, database

I am trying to produce a table that lists all the area code, office code combinations and the number of subscribers with that area code, office code combination.

```
CREATE TABLE lines 
(
    portid integer NOT NULL primary key,
    areacode varchar(3), --subscriber area code
    officecode varchar(3), --subscriber office code
    stationcode varchar(4), --subscriber station code
    state varchar(4) NOT NULL, --line state BUSY, IDLE

    foreign key (portid) references facilities(portid) on delete cascade
);

CREATE TABLE subscribers 
(
    portid integer NOT NULL,
    name varchar(30) NOT NULL,
    address varchar(50),
    primary key (portid, name),
    foreign key (portid)  references facilities(portid) on delete cascade
);

SELECT 
    AREACODE, OFFICECODE, COUNT(SUBSCRIBERS.PORTID = LINES.PORTID)
FROM 
    LINES
INNER JOIN 
    SUBSCRIBERS ON SUBSCRIBERS.PORTID = LINES.PORTID;
```

But this just outputs 819|227|50. It is outputting the total number of subscribers instead of the number of subscribers for each areacode and officecode combination. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: About to leave for lunch, so no time for a full answer, but the short version is `GROUP BY`

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use something along the lines of:

```
SELECT LINES.AREACODE, LINES.OFFICECODE, COUNT(*) AS SUBS
FROM LINES INNER JOIN SUBSCRIBERS ON SUBSCRIBERS.PORTID=LINES.PORTID
GROUP BY LINES.AREACODE, LINES.OFFICECODE
```

Without the `GROUP BY` clause, the query will output a row for each record in the joined dataset.

To output records for which the count meets some criteria, you would add a `HAVING` clause, e.g.:

```
SELECT LINES.AREACODE, LINES.OFFICECODE, COUNT(*) AS SUBS
FROM LINES INNER JOIN SUBSCRIBERS ON SUBSCRIBERS.PORTID=LINES.PORTID
GROUP BY LINES.AREACODE, LINES.OFFICECODE
HAVING COUNT(*) = 3
```

Comment: Yes, it seems to work thank you. So how would I go about only outputting rows with a certain count value say 3?

Answer (score 0):

A group by or maybe a nested select could get you to what you want, I came up with

```
SELECT areacode, officecode, lines.portid, count(*) from lines inner join 
subscribers on subscribers.portid=lines.portid group by areacode, officecode;
```